# Limit the output of ODEINT Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, odeint

I'm trying to define 'hard' limits to the return values of Scipy's odeint function but am unsure if function allows for such.  I've modified this example from [Scipy Cookbook](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/CoupledSpringMassSystem.html) so that the coupled two bodied system could collide.

Image Link

[image]

Graph Collision

[image]

Imaginary Stop

[image]

Specifically, the spring constant and mass have been changed to be weaker and lighter.  You'll also notice the 'if' statement used inside the function trying to limit the travel of 'm1' no further than the initial input of 'x2'.  Sorry, I don't have enough reputation points to post the graphs, but you'll clearly see the two masses can occupy the same space during portions of the solution.

```
# Use ODEINT to solve the differential equations defined by the vector field
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def vectorfield(w, t, p):
"""
Defines the differential equations for the coupled spring-mass system.

Arguments:
    w :  vector of the state variables:
              w = [x1,y1,x2,y2]
    t :  time
    p :  vector of the parameters:
              p = [m1,m2,k1,k2,L1,L2,b1,b2]
"""
x1, y1, x2, y2 = w
m1, m2, k1, k2, L1, L2, b1, b2 = p

# Create f = (x1',y1',x2',y2'):
f = [y1,
     (-b1 * y1 - k1 * (x1 - L1) + k2 * (x2 - x1 - L2)) / m1,
     y2,
     (-b2 * y2 - k2 * (x2 - x1 - L2)) / m2]

if y1 > x2:
    y1 == x2
else:
    y1 == y1

return f


# Parameter values
# Masses:
m1 = 0.5
m2 = 1.5
# Spring constants
k1 = 0.1
k2 = 40.0
# Natural lengths
L1 = 0.5
L2 = 1.0
# Friction coefficients
b1 = 0.8
b2 = 0.5

# Initial conditions
# x1 and x2 are the initial displacements; y1 and y2 are the initial velocities
x1 = 0.5
y1 = 0.0
x2 = 4.25
y2 = 0.0

# ODE solver parameters
abserr = 1.0e-8
relerr = 1.0e-6
stoptime = 5.0
numpoints = 2500

# Create the time samples for the output of the ODE solver.
# I use a large number of points, only because I want to make
# a plot of the solution that looks nice.
t = [stoptime * float(i) / (numpoints - 1) for i in range(numpoints)]

# Pack up the parameters and initial conditions:
p = [m1, m2, k1, k2, L1, L2, b1, b2]
w0 = [x1, y1, x2, y2]

# Call the ODE solver.
wsol = odeint(vectorfield, w0, t, args=(p,),
              atol=abserr, rtol=relerr)

plt.plot(t, wsol[:, 0], 'b', label='theta(t)')
plt.plot(t, wsol[:, 2], 'g', label='omega(t)')
plt.show()
```

I'm unsure if my variables are not being set up correctly, or if the odeint function cannot accept these types of 'limits' I'm trying to add.  Ideally, it would be nice if an 'upper boundary' could be set, if the displacement of the mass were beyond that value, it could then be set equal to a maximum limit of sorts.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Welcome to SC. Please provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your Problem. Your example is a modified copy from the Scipy Cookbook. Futhermore, what is the problem with your code? Does it produce an error? If so, what does the traceback say?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm using the Scipy Cookbook just as an example, and do not have a specific problem with my code just yet.  I'm exploring the versatility of the odeint function before constructing my code, as this will help determine my path forward.  There is no error with the above example, I've edited my original post to include the displacement graph of the odeint solution.  You will notice the blocks can 'collide', I'm interested in placing a limit on how far the block one can travel, say at 2.5 inches.  This would essentially cut the top of the graphs off.

Comment: I understand that the object you are referring to collides with that wall, what kind of shock is it, elastic, inelastic or plastic?

Comment: The 'wall' is meant to only limit the ability for the block to travel.  I'd like to have the ability to change the output such that: if x>2.5 then x = 2.5, else if x <= 2.5 then x = x.  I hope this makes sense, I'm only interested in 'restricting' the movement of the block inside odeint function output.  I'm afraid i may need to write a special integration function to accept these types of inputs.